# Finding $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$ given $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = 1$ where $ x < y < x+ 1$

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, covariance

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous random variables such that $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = 1$ where $ x < y < x+ 1$.

Find $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$.

For this question, I started by finding $E[X]$.

$E[X] = [ \int_{0}^{1} x \,dx] =1$.

Now, I am stuck on how to find $E[Y]$.

$E[Y] = [ \int_{x}^{x+1} y \,dy]$

Obviously, this integral won't give me a constant value. Is there something else I should consider for the bounds of $E[Y]$?

I was also thinking of using the formula of $E[Y] = E[E[Y\mid X]]$. Which I think would also be:

$E[Y\mid X] = [ \int_{x}^{x+1} y \,dy]$

But I'm not entirely sure if this is correct either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it should be
$$E[X] = \int_0^1 x \: dx = \frac{1}{2}.$$
You are correct that $E[Y]$ should not depend on $x$ so the formula $E[Y] = \int_x^{x+1} y \: dy$ is *wrong.* However the expression $\int_x^{x+1} y \: dy$ is useful, as it is the conditional expectation of $Y$ when the value $X=x$ is known. That is
$$E[Y \: | \: X=x] = \int_x^{x+1}y \: dy = \frac{1}{2}((x+1)^2 - x^2)$$
This gives us that
$$E[Y\:|\: X] = \frac{1}{2}((X+1)^2 - X^2) = \frac{1}{2} + X$$
Finally you can use the law total expectation to compute
$$E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]] = E[\frac{1}{2} + X] = 1$$
To compute the covariance you would need to also compute $E[YX]$, which can be done using the same method (that is by first considering the conditional expectation $E[XY|X=x]$), but it can also be done directly using
$$E[XY] = \int_0^1 \int_x^{x+1} xy \: dy \: dx.$$

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I made a typo - it should've been 1/2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the law of total covariance?
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(X, Y) &= \mathbb{E}[\text{Cov}(X, Y|X)] + \text{Cov}(\mathbb{E}[X|X], \mathbb{E}[Y|X]) \\
&= 0 + \text{Cov}\left(X, \frac{1}{2} + X\right) \\
&= \text{Var}(X) = \frac{1}{12}
\end{align*}
Another way to do this is observe that $Y = U + X$ for $U\sim \text{Unif}(0, 1)$ and independent of $X$. We also have
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(X, Y) = \text{Cov}(X, X + U) = \text{Cov}(X, X) + \text{Cov}(X, U) = \text{Var}(X) = \frac{1}{12}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, do you possibly have an idea how to do it the way I've approached it?